# LC-3 algorithm for converting ASCII strings to Binary Values

Tags: binary, computer-science, lc3

Figure 10.4 provides an algorithm for converting ASCII strings to binary values. Suppose the decimal number is arbitrarily long. Rather than store a table of 10 values for the thousands-place digit, another table for the 10 ten-thousands-place digit, and so on, design an algorithm to do the conversion without resorting to any tables whatsoever.

I have attached pictures of figure 10.4. I am not looking for an answer to the problem, but rather can someone please explain this problem and perhaps give some direction on how to go about creating the algorithm?
[Figure 10.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUUjZ.png)
[Figure 10.4 second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEbOp.png)

I am unsure as to what it means by tables and do not know where to start really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables are those global, initialized arrays: one called `Lookup10` holding 10, 20, 30, 40, ..., and another called `Lookup100` holding 100, 200, 300, 400...

You can ignore the tables: as per the assignment instructions you're supposed to find a different way to accomplish this anyway.  Or, you can run that code in simulator or mentally to understand how it works.

---

The bottom line is that LC-3, while it can do anything (it is turning complete), it can't do much in any one instruction.  For arithmetic & logic, it can do `add`, `not`, `and`.  That's pretty much it!  But that's enough — let's note that modern hardware does everything with only one logic gate, namely `NAND`, which is a binary operator (so `NAND` directly available; `NOT` by providing `NAND` with the same operand for both inputs; `AND` by doing `NOT` after `NAND`; `OR` using NOT on both inputs first and then `NAND`; etc..)

For example, LC-3 cannot multiply or divide or modulus or right shift directly — each of those operations is many instructions and in the general case, some looping construct.  Multiplication can be done by repetitive addition, and division/modulus by repetitive subtraction.  These are super inefficient for larger operands, and there are much more efficient algorithms that are also substantially more complex, so those greatly increase program complexity beyond that already with the repetitive operation approach.

---

That subroutine goes backwards through the use input string.  It takes a string length count in R1 as parameter supplied by caller (not shown).  It looks at the last character in the input and converts it from an ASCII character to a binary number.

(We would commonly do that conversion from ascii character to numeric value using subtraction: moving the character values from the ascii character range of 0x30..0x39 to numeric values in the range 0..9, but they do it with masking, which also works.  The subtraction approach integrates better with error detection (checking if not a valid digit character, which is not done here), whereas the masking approach is simpler for LC-3.)

The subroutine then obtains the 2nd last digit (moving backwards through the user's input string), converting that to binary using the mask approach.  That yields a number between 0 and 9, which is used as an index into the first table `Lookup10`.  The value obtained from the table at that index position is basically the index × 10.  So this table is a × 10 table.  The same approach is used for the third (and first or, last-going-backwards) digit, except it uses the 2nd table which is a × 100 table.

---

The standard approach for string to binary is called `atoi` (search it) standing for ascii to integer.  It moves *forwards* through the string, and for every new digit, it multiples the existing value, computed so far, by 10 before adding in the next digit's numeric value.

So, if the string is 456, the first it obtains 4, then because there is another digit, 4 × 10 = 40, then + 5 for 45, then × 10 for 450, then + 6 for 456, and so on.

The advantage of this approach is that it can handle any number of digits (up to overflow).  The disadvantage, of course, is that it requires multiplication, which is a complication for LC-3.

---

Multiplication where one operand is the constant 10 is fairly easy even in LC-3's limited capabilities, and can be done with simple addition without looping.  Basically:

- n × 10 = n + n + n + n + n + n + n + n + n + n

and LC-3 can do those 9 additions in just 9 instructions.  Still, we can also observe that:

- n × 10 = n × 8 + n × 2

and also that:

- n × 10 = (n × 4 + n) × 2      (which is n × 5 × 2)

which can be done in just 4 instructions on LC-3 (and none of these needs looping)!

---

So, if you want to do this approach, you'll have to figure out how to go forwards through the string instead of backwards as the given table version does, and, how to multiply by 10 (use any one of the above suggestions).

There are other approaches as well if you study `atoi`.  You could keep the backwards approach, but now will have to multiply by 10, by 100, by 1000, a different factor for each successive digit .  That might be done by repetitive addition.  Or a count of how many times to multiply by 10 — e.g. n × 1000 = n × 10 × 10 × 10.